# how to replace NA when exporting

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace the `NA`'s in my output file with a blank. I'm combining columns from two different Excel workbooks with different column names. I added a picture of the output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx',recursive = TRUE)
file_names<-sapply(file.list,read_excel,simplify = FALSE)
df<-rbind.fill(file_names)
df1<- select(df,"Location Address",City,State,ZIP,address1,address2,city,state,zip)
df1<-unite(vf1,'Full Address',"Location Address",City,State,ZIP,address1,address2,city,state,zip,sep = ",")
write.csv(df1,"adv134.csv",row.names =FALSE,na = "0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for:

```
write.csv(df1,"adv134.csv",row.names =FALSE,na = "")
```

This will fill any NA values in the data frame as blanks (there is nothing between the quotes).

Comment: i did that and it still prints the NA's